# How do I set revert back to conditions after an onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I what i want to create is where when a certain a div is clicked, the innerHTML changes, but i want it to go back after the click may after one second

```
 function setWheels() {
     document.querySelector(".blue-wheel").innerHTML = "<img src='blue-dark.svg.svg' id='blue-wheel-id' onclick='buttonEvent()'>";
  }

 function buttonEvent() {
      document.querySelector(".blue-wheel").innerHTML = "<img src='blue-light.svg.svg'>";
  }
```

right now as soon as the page loads, the setWheels function is called leading to the innerHTML to be that specific image. And when clicked it becomes the new one per the buttonEvent() function but it stays on that image and I would like it to go back to the other image after around one second.
For reference other features will be added onto the buttonEvent such as audio may be more than one second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`setTimeout()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) method.

```
function setWheels() {
    document.querySelector(".blue-wheel").innerHTML = "<img src='blue-dark.svg.svg' id='blue-wheel-id' onclick='buttonEvent()'>";
}

function buttonEvent() {
    document.querySelector(".blue-wheel").innerHTML = "<img src='blue-light.svg.svg'>";
    setTimeout(setWheels, 1000);
}
```

Comment: say if I were to add another wheel to the setWheels function, would i use an if statement in the buttonEvent() to check what wheel it is, then do the setTimeout

Comment: @ryan Do you want the other wheel to handle the click event ? Do you want to set a different Timeout depending on the wheel which was clicked ?

Comment: as seen above the light blue wheel corresponds to the dark blue wheel, there are another 3 wheels that will be added such as a dark red wheel that onclick will be a light red wheel

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to change the html.

Use a css class to define the background (image), [classList.toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) to switch the background, and [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) to revert after a certain time.

It is generally [not a good idea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) to use inline event handlers. The snippet (mockup) uses [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) for handling the click.

[**edit**] Snippet edited based on OP's question:

> say if I were to add another wheel to the setWheels function, would i
> use an if statement in the buttonEvent() to check what wheel it is,
> then do the setTimeout

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle); 

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
  `beforeend`, `<div class="switch blue"></div><div class="switch green"></div>` );

function handle(evt) {
  const isSwitchElem = evt.target.closest(`.switch:not(.switched)`);
  
  if (isSwitchElem) {
    isSwitchElem.classList.toggle(`switched`);
    setTimeout(() => isSwitchElem.classList.toggle(`switched`), 1000);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 2rem;
  font: normal 12px/15px verdana, arial;
}

.switch {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background: no-repeat left center;
  background-size: 64px;
  background-repeat: none;
  padding: 3px 3px 3px 22px;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
}


.switch.blue {
  background-image: url(//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5a/Button_Icon_BlueSky.svg);
}

.switch.green {
  background-image: url(//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Button_Icon_GreenYellow.svg);
}

.switched.blue {
  background-image: url(//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3f/Button_Icon_Blue.svg);
}

.switched.green {
  background-image: url(//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1e/Button_Icon_GreenForest.svg);
}

.switched:after {
  content: " Wait in a sec ...";
  margin-left: 68px;
  line-height: 64px;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<h3>Click the dots</h3>
```